# ARKit API by example

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to wrap my head around Apple's ARKit API and I have pushed their [example `ARKitExample` project](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/ARKitExample) up to GitHub.

In this demo/sample project, you move your phone camera around your environment, and it *appears* to automatically detect flat surfaces and place a set of "focus squares" over where your camera is centered over that surface. If you then press a `"+"` UI button and select from one of several objects (lamp, cups, vase, etc.) and it will render that virtual object in place of the focus squares. You can see all of this in action [right here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-o7qr1NpeNI) which is probably better than me trying to explain it!

I'm trying to find the place in the code where the virtual object is actually invoked and rendered onscreen. This would be just after it is selected, which I *think* takes place [here](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/ARKitExample/blob/master/ViewController%2BActions.swift#L20):

```
@IBAction func chooseObject(_ button: UIButton) {
    // Abort if we are about to load another object to avoid concurrent modifications of the scene.
    if isLoadingObject { return }

    textManager.cancelScheduledMessage(forType: .contentPlacement)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueIdentifier.showObjects.rawValue, sender: button)
}
```

But essentially, the user selects a virtual object and then it gets rendered wherever the focus square are currently located at -- I'm looking for where this happens, any ideas?

Comment: you are close. the `performSegue` function should tell you that the action happened in another `ViewController`, in this case `ViewController+ObjectSelection.swift` and more specifically, `virtualObjectSelectionViewController(_: VirtualObjectSelectionViewController, didSelectObjectAt index: Int)`.

Comment: Thanks @axelspark (+1) - so it looks like `virtualObjectManager.loadVirtualObject` is where objects get loaded to a particular location on screen then?

Comment: it gets loaded yes but not to a particular location on the device's screen. the third parameter of that function transforms the "screen-local" coordinate to a "real world-global" coordinate so you can move your camera view "off the device's screen" but the object still remains at the same position when you move the camera back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds the virtualObject instance (which is a subclass of SCNNode) as a child of the SCNScene's root node:

```
    func virtualObjectSelectionViewController(_: VirtualObjectSelectionViewController, didSelectObjectAt index: Int) {
    guard let cameraTransform = session.currentFrame?.camera.transform else {
        return
    }

    let definition = VirtualObjectManager.availableObjects[index]
    let object = VirtualObject(definition: definition)
    let position = focusSquare?.lastPosition ?? float3(0)
    virtualObjectManager.loadVirtualObject(object, to: position, cameraTransform: cameraTransform)
    if object.parent == nil {
        serialQueue.async {
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(object)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks @leandrodemarco (+1) - so it looks like `virtualObjectManager.loadVirtualObject` is the ARKit function that actually loads virtual objects to a particular location on screen then?

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, if you start digging in that call you'll see that it sets the virtualObject (node) position in the `setNewVirtualObjectPosition` function. Side note, that property is more of SCNKit than ARKit properly

Comment: Ahh thanks again @leandrodemarco (+1 again), and it *sounds* like SCNKit is kind of like Apple's OpenGL (graphics lib) that acts as ARKit's foundation? Thanks again!

Comment: I do not really know how SceneKit processes and renders under the hood, but I'd guess it uses Metal. ARKit comes ready to work in conjuction either with SceneKit for 3D objects, SpriteKit for 2D or Metal for custom rendering. You can see a basic example that uses SpriteKit if you create a new project and the Augmented Reality app template. There you can select which of those 3 frameworks you want ARKit to work with.